# Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [RotatingNavController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, orientation, ios8

Following an upgrade to iOS8, my favorite app is throwing this error

> 2014-09-24 11:07:20.573 My Favorite App[199:8521] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation',
>   reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the
>   application, and [RotatingNavController shouldAutorotate] is returning
>   YES'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x183b4e084 0x1944400e4 0x183b4dfc4 0x188344c8c 0x18834478c 0x1883443a8 0x10004f0a4 0x1883425d0
>   0x188558de8 0x18855b568 0x188559c00 0x18bd15640 0x183b06360
>   0x183b05468 0x183b03668 0x183a31664 0x18833b98c 0x188336984
>   0x10004ec94 0x194aaea08) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension / category.

swift solution here

```
extension RotatingNavController {
    func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```